# Use macro expansion to create multiple #define constants

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I am working on an open gl driver and need to define a set of constants using #define. The names of these constants iterate along with the value they represent. They are also bounded by a max value set by another #define which is hardware specific. I would like to define the these constants using the max value if possible.

Currently I have defined them as follows:

```
#define GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS 24
#define GL_TEXTURE0  0
#define GL_TEXTURE1  1
...
#define GL_TEXTURE24 24
```

I would like to have something along the lines of the following:

```
#define GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS 24
#define GL_TEXTURE(SOMETRICKYMACRO)
```

Where the macro is defined in such a way that at compilation I end up with an expansion equivalent to the first case but if I wanted to change the number of constants I would only need to modify GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS.

Comment: This might be a stupid question (I don't know OpenGL in that kind of depth), but do the constants have to be `#define`d, or would an `enum` do the job? If so that changes the answer significantly, and you can use one of several CPP metaprogramming "dirty tricks" to do what you want quite easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C preprocessor cannot produce new preprocessing directives itself. If you want to do something like this, you would need to generate the header file with a separate utility (perhaps a shell or awk script) as part of your build process.

If you find yourself really needing something like this (programmatically variable range of values), it might be an indication that referring to them symbolically via macro names is a bad design choice.

Comment: Unfortunately those constants are part of the OpenGL spec. Can't really avoid them.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen is correct, the design choice was made by Silicon Graphics a long, long time ago.